# Unity 5.1.03f Stopped working on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded unity 5.1.03f 64bit editor for windows and installed it.
Installation is error free.When finished the installation, When tring to open the unity, the following error is showing. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Errr, this isn't Unity support.

Comment: it happns everytime you start unity? did you try any other machine or didi you install latest unity updates?